# How can I order multiple columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in my mysql:

`| id | category_id | region_id | score |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+
|  1 |           1 |         1 |    78 |
|  2 |           1 |         2 |    65 |
|  3 |           1 |         3 |    98 |
|  4 |           1 |         4 |    45 |
|  5 |           1 |         5 |    78 |
|  6 |           1 |         1 |    98 |
|  7 |           1 |         2 |    32 |
|  8 |           1 |         3 |    56 |
|  9 |           1 |         4 |    89 |
| 10 |           1 |         5 |    65 |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+`

I want to get the 5 latest id but order my result table base on region id so I used this code

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tb_scores 
 WHERE category_id = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC
     , region_id ASC
 LIMIT 5
```

but the result only sorted the id as desc but not the region_id as ASC..to explain briefly I want this kind of result.

```
| id | category_id | region_id | score |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+
|  6 |           1 |         1 |    98 |
|  7 |           1 |         2 |    32 |
|  8 |           1 |         3 |    56 |
|  9 |           1 |         4 |    89 |
| 10 |           1 |         5 |    65 |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: How do you determine what is 'latest' as there is no date column? Purely by ID?

Comment: yes..the column is auto incremented

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   tb_scores
        WHERE  category_id = 1
        ORDER  BY id DESC,region_id ASC LIMIT 5) t
ORDER  BY region_id
```

get your data in subquery and apply `order by region_id` on the subquery result.